# Execute a function from dynamic button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm creating a table, after that I convert table to jQuery dataTable, for this I'm using `dataTable.responsive` and an option to display information in a modal, problem here is that my function button is only displayed on the modal, so my question is what can I do to access to that button, I'm trying doing this but do not work.

```
$('#TableBody').on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function () {
    alert("Click!");
});
```

This do not work too:

```
//example is my table id
$('#example').on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function () {
    alert("Click!");
});
```

Here is my [full code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozVrPa) to see my problem properly.

Comment: And if you do `$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-edit'...` does that work

Comment: @adeneo Yes! that work, but what if I have more than one input with .glyphicon-edit? Should I use a personalized class or id?

Comment: You should use the closest ***non-dynamic*** parent element. Meaning, you should use the closest parent that isn't replaced by the dataTables plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap styling, use the code below. This will narrow your selector to the element in the modal opened by jQuery DataTables.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dtr-bs-modal .glyphicon-edit', function(){
   // ... skipped ...
});
```